# Eclipse does not detect my Sony Xperia Z1 Compact

Tags: android, eclipse, sony-xperia

I have updated Eclipse. Eclipse can detect and run apps on a Samsung Galaxy ACE 2, but it does not detect a Sony Xperia Z1 Compact.

I have done the following:

- I have activated the Z1 for development (7 clicks).
- I have enabled the USB connection mode = MSC (Mass Storage Mode)
- I have disabled Install Software option (USB Connectivity --> Install Software OFF).
- I have restarted both Windows and my phone.
- I have reinstalled Xperia Z1 Compact drivers on Windows 7 from http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/

Nothing of this has worked.

The ADB won't recognize the device.

Z1 Compact operating system is 4.4.4

Anyone knows anything else I could try or what may be going on?

Comment: 7 clicks + debug mode ON, check that. Also you MUST update your platform & platform-tools in SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`phone->setting->developer option->USB debugging mode` enable it and try hope it will solve your problem.